# Configuring DHCP IPv4 and static IPv6 on the same interface

Tags: centos, ipv6, ipv4

I need to configure on a network interface (`eth1`) with static IPv6 and get an IPv4 address from DHCP on a CentOS 6 machine?

Using the configuration below I only get a dynamic IPv4 address:

```
DEVICE=eth1
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
ONBOOT=yes
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6ADDR=2140::1/64
```

But there is no global IPv6 address assigned.

Comment: Does your system actually support IPv6?

Comment: Yes it supports IPv6 I've been able to set static IPv6 Only.

Comment: I guess static address is ignored since BOOTPROTO=DHCP. Why do not you make reservation for IPv6 on the same DHCP server?

Comment: The same DHCP server does not provide ipv6 addresses only IPv4 addresses.

Comment: Then try to make alias eth:0 and custom IP setup for It.